# 'Curved' vs 'Straight' Curves

Tags: bezier-curves

How can I make the square round or the circle square? I'm at a loss for why curves are sometimes linear and sometimes smooth. How can that be changed?

[image: un-interpolated curve and interpolated curve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just change handle type and spline type in edit mode

[image]

Comment: It should be Alt-C not Ctrl-C. The 'video is an animated Gif image probably produced by something like [ScreentoGif](https://www.screentogif.com/).

Comment: tbh i don't know what you mean with "breaks". You can create a gif (with whatever app you like) and then just drag'n drop or copy paste it in.